# Best way to merge two SQL queries into one query

Tags: sql, count, sum, case

I have two small SQL queries that I would like to merge to be a single query that I will eventually use in a stored procedure.  I have tried a CASE and IF/ELSE but could not get it to work.  Below is the code.  What I want to achieve is have the first column 'Count of Open Order Lines' based on both where statements from both queries but the second column 'Sum Quantity' only based on the where statement from the second query.

```
select 
COUNT(OO.ORNO) AS 'Count of Open Order Lines'
from OOLINE OO
    join OOHEAD OH
    on OO.CONO = OH.CONO
    and OO.ORNO = OH.ORNO
where OO.ORST BETWEEN 22 AND 66
    and OH.OBLC BETWEEN 1 AND 8;


select 
CAST(SUM(OO.ORQT) AS DECIMAL (8,0)) AS 'Sum Quantity'
from OOLINE OO
    join OOHEAD OH
    on OO.CONO = OH.CONO
    and OO.ORNO = OH.ORNO
where OO.ORST BETWEEN 22 AND 66;
```

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Are you using [[tag:mysql]] or [[tag:sql-server]]. Also what does this have to do with (SQL Server's) [[tag:sql-query-store]]? I don't see anything that is related to this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN OH.OBLC BETWEEN 1 AND 8 THEN OO.ORNO END) AS "Count_of_Open_Order_Lines",
       CAST(SUM(OO.ORQT) AS DECIMAL (8,0)) AS Sum_Quantity
FROM OOLINE OO INNER JOIN OOHEAD OH
ON OO.CONO = OH.CONO AND OO.ORNO = OH.ORNO
WHERE OO.ORST BETWEEN 22 AND 66;
```

In the `WHERE` clause I kept only the condition `OO.ORST BETWEEN 22 AND 66` which is common in both queries and for `Count of Open Order Lines` I used a `CASE` expression based on the condition `OH.OBLC BETWEEN 1 AND 8`.

Comment: Thanks @forpas this did the trick.  My original case statement was set up wrong.  I had CASE(COUNT and SUM(CAST.  Appreciate the help.